# Unable to execute POST requests using Python script due to token expiration issue

Tags: python, https, http-post

"I've developed a Python script that generates an authentication token for use in various GET and POST requests. When this token is utilized in GET requests to fetch user information, it works flawlessly, and we receive the expected response.

However, when the same token is employed in POST requests to create groups, it results in a '401 Unauthorized' status error with the following message:

{'meta': {'status': 'Unauthorized', 'timestamp': '2023-10-19T13:09:53.917+0000', 'message': 'token is expired'}}

I am confident that the token is still valid, and all the necessary variables are correctly defined. Is there a known issue related to using Python to access Swagger APIs for POST requests, or could there be something I'm overlooking? Any insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated."

Here is the code snippet:

```
import requests
import json

# Define the OAuth2 token endpoint
token_endpoint = 'https://URL/rest/oauth/token'  # Replace with your token endpoint

# Define your OAuth2 parameters (client_id, client_secret, and other required parameters)
client_id = 'CID'
client_secret = 'CSECRET'
grant_type = 'client_credentials'  # Specify the grant type you need

# Define the data payload
data = {
    #'client_id': client_id,
    #'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': grant_type,
    # Additional parameters specific to your OAuth2 setup
    # For 'password' grant type, you typically need 'username' and 'password' as well
    #'username': '***',
    #'password': '****!'
}

# Make a POST request to the token endpoint to obtain an access token
response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=data)
print(response.status_code)

if response.status_code == 200:
    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
    print(f'Access Token: {access_token}')
else:
    print(f'Failed to obtain the access token. Status code: {response.status_code}')

checkuserurl='https://URL/rest/v1/users?username=smohan1'
headers={
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+str(access_token)
     }
 
response2 = requests.get(
     checkuserurl,
     headers=headers
     )
result2=response2.json()
print(result2)
#################################################################################################

gcURL = 'https://URL/rest/v1/usergroups'
data = {
        "name": 'Test Group',
        "description": 'Test Group',
        "project": 20755
        }
headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str({access_token})
          }
gcresponse = requests.post(
             gcURL,
             headers=headers,
             data=data
            )
gcresult = gcresponse.json()
print(gcresult)
print(gcresponse.status_code)
```

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str({access_token})` Why do you have `{}` around access_token?  `{}` is Python syntax for a set.  You're making a string of a single-element set, which is surely not what you meant to do...

Comment: Hey John, Thanks for Responding. When I tried removing the {}, the below error occurred : {'meta': {'status': 'Bad Request', 'timestamp': '2023-10-20T13:48:02.861+0000', 'message': "Unrecognized token 'name': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'fal
se')\n at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 6]"}}

Comment: Since you're trying to send json, use `json=data` instead of `data=data` in the `requests.post()` call.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you so much for this fix. That worked like magic. These minor tweaks are no where mentioned in any of the documentation. Atleast, I didnt come across one yet. You saved many many hours of troubleshooting. :)